# Angular: trying to add recaptcha. Error => No value accessor for form control with name: 'captcha'

Tags: javascript, angular, captcha

So I followed a tutorial on how to add recaptcha to a form to prevent spam. I followed all the steps, but I still get the following error:

```
 error inside log Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'captcha'
    at _throwError (forms.js:2139)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2008)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5144)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:5743)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5684)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:11642)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13252)
```

I have a reactive signup form where I have the following element that's supposed to be the captcha and a formControl. BUt unfortunately I see nothing.

```
<div nbRecaptcha key="6LfNfHYUAAAAAFaa7dVi2au1tnfod-2eR3Rb2enM" formControlName="captcha"></div>
```

This is the nbRecaptcha directive:

```
declare const grecaptcha: any;

declare global {
  interface Window {
    grecaptcha: any;
    reCaptchaLoad: () => void
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[nbRecaptcha]',
  providers: [ReCaptchaAsyncValidator]
})
export class RecaptchaDirective implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() key: string;
  @Input() config: ReCaptchaConfig = {};
  @Input() lang: string;

  private control: FormControl;

  private onChange: ( value: string ) => void;
  private onTouched: ( value: string ) => void;
  private widgetId: number;

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private injector: Injector,
    private reCaptchaAsyncValidator: ReCaptchaAsyncValidator){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerReCaptchaCallback();
    this.addScript();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.control = this.injector.get(NgControl).control;
    this.setValidator();
  }

  addScript() {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    const lang = this.lang ? '&hl=' + this.lang : '';
    script.src = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=reCaptchaLoad&render=explicit${lang}`;
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }


  //  We need to notify the formControl that it’s valid if we get the token
  // from the onSuccess function or that it’s invalid if the onExpired function is called.

  onExpired() {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.onChange(null);
      this.onTouched(null);
    });
  }

  onSuccess( token: string ) {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.verifyToken(token);
      this.onChange(token);
      this.onTouched(token);
    });
  }

  //  these are the three methods that controlValueAccessor requires

  writeValue( obj: any ): void {
  }

  registerOnChange( fn: any ): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched( fn: any ): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  private setValidator() {
    this.control.setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.control.updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  registerReCaptchaCallback() {
    window.reCaptchaLoad = () => {
      const config = {
        ...this.config,
        'sitekey': this.key,
        'callback': this.onSuccess.bind(this),
        'expired-callback': this.onExpired.bind(this)
      };
      this.widgetId = this.render(this.element.nativeElement, config);
    };
  }

  private render( element: HTMLElement, config ): number {
    return grecaptcha.render(element, config);
  }

  verifyToken( token : string ) {
    this.control.setAsyncValidators(this.reCaptchaAsyncValidator.validateToken(token))
    this.control.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

And the signup component form:

```
this.mySignupForm = new FormGroup({
          captcha: new FormControl()
        });
```

**Can Anyone see what I did wrong?**

Comment: You are using the new FormControl constructor within an object... try captcha: [‘’]

Comment: That causes an error. "type string[] is not assignable to type 'abstractControl'"

Comment: In your constructor declare private fb: FormGroup then this.mySignupForm= this.fb({ captcha: [‘’]});

Comment: Never tried that with directive but in components you must have `{
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CompName),
      multi: true
    }`...in providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `No value accessor for form control with name: 'captcha'`. This can be resolved by adding the directive/control to list of all available `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`s using `forwardRef`. You are effectively extending the multi-provider for `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` so that this directive can access `ControlValueAccessor`.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[nbRecaptcha]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => RecaptchaDirective),
      multi: true
    },
    ReCaptchaAsyncValidator
  ]
})
```

Here is a mostly working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnpj3m) with that specific error being resolved. I had to remove some of the custom classes/configurations you had in your example as I wasn't aware of their exact implementations.

I could not find official [documentation](https://angular.io/docs) for creating custom controls, but there are a few solid articles out there discussing creating custom controls that reference this necessary registration.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we get this kind of error when import it in app.module instead of the own module where we need to use . for example

```
///app.module.ts 
import { RecaptchaModule, RecaptchaFormsModule  } from "ng-recaptcha";
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RecaptchaModule,
    RecaptchaFormsModule
]
```

move it to --->

```
///x.module.ts
import { RecaptchaModule, RecaptchaFormsModule  } from "ng-recaptcha";
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    RecaptchaModule,
    RecaptchaFormsModule,
],
providers:[
   {
     provide: RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS,
      useValue: { siteKey: environment.recaptcha.siteKey } as RecaptchaSettings,
    },
]
```